# Bound value to a hiddenfield inside a datalist is not specific to an item

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, hiddenfield

I'm a beginner for asp.net(C#) and I'm working on a social networking application. I've stuck on the status update and comment section. I want that when page is loaded all the threads(status') should have their IDs in their hiddenfields inside the datalist as I've created an ItemTemplate for status and assigned Thread_ID to the hiddenfield. But the problem is that hiddenfield is not having different values for the different Items. I don't know where I'm doing the mistake. Please help me.

Here is the code for datalist:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListStatus" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1"
            onitemdatabound="DataListStatus_ItemDataBound"
            onitemcommand="DataListStatus_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table width="550px">
                <tr><asp:HiddenField ID="HFieldThreadID" Value='<%#Eval("Thread_ID") %>' runat="server" />
                    <td style="vertical-align:top; width:50px;" align="left" rowspan="3"><a href='UserProfile.aspx?loginid=<%#Eval("RegID")%>' ><img alt="Propic" src="../Images/ProPic.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" /></a></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top; width:250px;" align="left"><a href='UserProfile.aspx?loginid=<%#Eval("RegID")%>' ><%#Eval("RegID")%></a></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top; width:250px;" align="right"><%#Eval("St_Time") %></td>
                </tr>
    </table>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Status where RegID='" + Session["user"].ToString() + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(ds, "status");
        con.Close();
        DataListStatus.DataSource = ds.Tables["status"];
        DataListStatus.DataBind();
    }

}
```

And here I'm using the hiddenfield's value in the inner datalist for the comments:

```
protected void DataListStatus_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Comment WHERE Thread_ID='" +      ((HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HFieldThreadID")).Value + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    da.Fill(ds, "cmts");
    con.Close();
    ((DataList)e.Item.FindControl("DataListCmt")).DataSource = ds.Tables["cmts"];
    ((DataList)e.Item.FindControl("DataListCmt")).DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice in `ItemDataBound` is you want to make sure `e.Item is` of type `Item` or  `AlternatingItem` before searching and binding controls inside item.

**NOTE**: please use Parameterized Query to avoid SQL injection.

```
protected void DataListStatus_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
      e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Comment WHERE Thread_ID='" +      ((HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HFieldThreadID")).Value + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    da.Fill(ds, "cmts");
    con.Close();
    var dataList = (DataList)e.Item.FindControl("DataListCmt");
    dataList.DataSource = ds.Tables["cmts"];
    dataList.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what is the effect of your suggestion on my code. Could you please tell me what does this check if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) do? By the way I was doing some other mistake. I was not clearing the dataset before assigning it to the next thread and that is why I was feeling that the value of hidden field was same. 
well thanks for answering.

Comment: NOTE: please use Parameterized Query to avoid SQL injection.
Thanks a lot for this suggestion. Actually I know this but I feel it's little tough and tedious so I may do this later. One more problem may be solved by this i.e. inserting single quote(').

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hidden field . Because the page load time this hidden-field field was cleared  .So please use label control and set visible="false" in   the label control.

And Must the DataList binding method call  Inside of !IsPostBack  in  pageload event

Comment: `hidden-field field was cleared on page load time` is ***not correct***, because `HiddenField` has view state. **A value stored in `HiddenField` persists between post back.**

Comment: `DataList binding method` is correct in @Don's code because it is **nested DataLists**.

Comment: @Win is right. And one more thing I want to use the code to be executed again and again with postbacks, so I can't put databinding method in !IsnotpostBack.
BTW thanks for answering.